# TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'

Tags: python, list, генераторы

Копаюсь в дандерах **iter** и **next** и решил написать свой класс, который при итерации возвращает свои атрибуты.
Самый первый пример, который мне пришёл в голову - это просто сбор всех атрибутов в отдельном листе и вывод их по одному:

```
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = -1
        self.list_q = [self.name, self.age]
        return self.list_q
        
    def __next__(self):
        index += 1
        yield self.list_q[self.index]
        
        
t = Test('Имя', 10)

for item in t:
    print(item)
```

Но при данном коде у меня получается ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    for item in t:
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'
```

В чём проблема? Разве метод **iter** не должен возвращать итератор для перебора объектов? Разве лист не является таким итератором?

Comment: list - это не итератор, это итерируемый объект. Чтобы был итератор, нужно вернуть `iter(self.list_q)`. Отличие итерируемого объекта от итератора в том, что у него `__iter__` возвращает итератор, но у самого итерируемого объекта метод `__next__` не реализован.

Comment: Разве цикл for самостоятельно не вызовет итератор объекта? Это же по сути обычный перебор листа

Comment: Цикл вызовет у объекта метод `__iter__`, из которого должен вернуться итератор. У итератора должен быть метод `__next__`, чтобы дальше получать значения из этого объекта. Но вы возвращаете список, у списка нет метода `__next__`, потому что он не итератор (буквально: попытка вызова `__next__` от списка выдаст `AttributeError`). Python правда это отлавливает на более раннем этапе, и сразу человеческим языком пишет, что list - не итератор.

Comment: @insolor О, вот то, что у списка нет метода `__next__` - это хорошее объяснение, это я и пропустил как-раз.

Comment: Я всё понял, мужики. Большое спасибо вам и вашим семьям. Счастья-здоровья, здоровья-счастья!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два разных понятия: итератор ([iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)), итерируемый объект ([iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)). У них есть схожие черты (и по тому, и по другому можно пройтись циклом), но есть большая разница.

С точки зрения реализации:

- итерируемый объект должен реализовать метод `__iter__`, из которого должен возвращаться итератор (но не другой итерируемый объект). В идеале - при каждом вызове новый итератор.
- итератор должен реализовывать и метод `__iter__` (который должен возвращать сам объект (`self`)), и метод `__next__`, который при каждом вызове должен возвращать следующее значение из итератора (или выбрасывает исключение `StopIteration`).

Чисто технически, каждый итератор можно считать итерируемым объектом - у каждого итератора реализован `__iter__` (который, правда, не создает новый итератор). Но не наоборот - не у каждого итерируемого объекта будет метод `__next__`. Поэтому и не работает возврат `list` из `__iter__` - он является итерируемым объектом, но не итератором.

С точки зрения поведения:

- После того как итератор создан, по нему можно пройти циклом (или, например, извлекать значения с помощью функции `next`) только один раз, при попытке пройти повторно итератор больше не возвращает никаких значений - так называемое исчерпание итератора (iterator exhaustion)
- По итерируемому объекту (кроме итераторов) можно итерироваться много раз - его метод `__iter__` каждый раз возвращает новый итератор.

  Хотя итератор формально (по наличию метода `__iter__`) можно считать итерируемым объектом, но `__iter__` у него не создает новый итератор, а просто возвращает сам объект, по которому уже нельзя пройти повторно, если он исчерпан.

По вашему коду:

- В принципе, если реализуете итератор, лучше не добавлять в `__iter__` никакого кода, кроме `return self`, а всю инициализацию делать в `__init__`.
- `__next__` должен именно возвращать значения через `return`, а не через `yield`. Если добавляете в функцию yield, то она магически становится [генератором](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-19), который возвращает итератор ([generator iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator), частный случай итератора), а вам нужно ровно одно значение, а не новый итератор.

Таким образом, класс-итератор в идеале должен выглядеть так:

```
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.index = -1
        self.list_q = [self.name, self.age]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
        
    def __next__(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.list_q):
            raise StopIteration
        return self.list_q[self.index]
```

Если вы реализуете итерируемый объект, то метод `__next__` не нужен, но `__iter__` должен вернуть итератор. Из списка можно получить итератор передав его в функцию `iter`:

```
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.list_q = [self.name, self.age]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.list_q)
        
        
t = Test('Имя', 10)

for item in t:
    print(item)
```

Либо можно использовать `yield` (как я уже писал выше, в этом случае функция превратится в генератор и будет возвращать итератор):

```
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.list_q = [self.name, self.age]

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.list_q:
            yield item
        
        
t = Test('Имя', 10)

for item in t:
    print(item)
```

Еще один способ - использовать выражение-генератор ([generator expresson](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#index-20)), оно также является итератором:

```
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.list_q = [self.name, self.age]

    def __iter__(self):
        return (item for item in self.list_q)
        
        
t = Test('Имя', 10)

for item in t:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Прояснили некоторые моменты про итераторы и итерируемые объекты

Comment: Да, я тоже для себя кое-что дополнительно прояснил )

Answer (score 2):

Ниже будет объяснение, почему возврат списка не работает, но в общем правильно будет из `__iter__` возвращать `self`, ну и `__next__` нужно переделать, у вас там сразу несколько ошибок:

```py
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = -1
        self.list_q = [self.name, self.age]
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index < len(self.list_q):
            return self.list_q[self.index]
        raise StopIteration

t = Test('Имя', 10)

for item in t:
    print(item)
```

Если взять от списка итератор, то работать тоже будет, но управлять отдачей из него элементов вы уже не сможете, `__next__` писать в вашем классе бесполезно в этом случае, будет использоваться `__next__` от итератора списка, а не ваш:

```py
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __iter__(self):
        self.list_q = [self.name, self.age]
        return iter(self.list_q)

t = Test('Имя', 10)

for item in t:
    print(item)
```

Как пояснил в комментариях insolor, возврат `self` как и возврат `iter` от списка работает, потому что питон проверяет, что у возвращаемого из метода `__iter__` объекта существует метод `__next__` и поэтому его можно использовать как итератор. А когда вы возвращаете просто список, то у него нет метода `__next__`, поэтому такая схема не работает.

Comment: А использование yield вместо return в методе __next__ необязательно?

Comment: Разве цикл for самостоятельно не вызовет итератор объекта? Это же по сути обычный перебор листа

Comment: @DarkSpace Я так понимаю, проблема в том, что он **уже вызвал** `iter` - у вашего класса. А у списка, который вы вернули, никто `iter` не вызвал.

Comment: @DarkSpace `yield` нужен только в случае, если вы хотите вернуть несколько значений по очереди в одной какой-то логике при обращении к методу (например, в цикле внутри метода). Если вы возвращаете ровно одно значение, то нет разницы между `yield` и `return`.

Comment: Я всё понял, большое спасибо

Comment: `iterable` и `iterator` в одном объекте - это очень плохо. Это работает пока у вас один цикл. Но если у вас несколько циклов по одному и тому же объекту - всё развалится. Пока вы разрабатываете и тестируете по простому, ошибка не видна. Если вы передадите ваш объект в `itertools.product(..., repeat=2)` - какая сказочная ждёт вас отладка!

Comment: `iterable.iter` всегда должен возвращать новый объект. `iterator.iter` всегда возвращает сам себя. Их нельзя совместить в принципе.

Comment: @CrazyElf, вы взрослый человек. Не учите новичков дурному.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да я сам всё ещё учусь, что вы от меня хотите! ))  Я вспомнил, что тема не простая. Может проще её задупликатить куда-нибудь?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy постарался в своем ответе это подробнее расписать

Comment: @DarkSpace Рекомендую принять ответ insolor-а, он более правильный и подробный )

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну раз хозяин ответа сказал, то тогда надо)